# Jira "Issue Statistic" gadget show number of tasks per team member

Tags: jira

I have an "Issue Statistic" gadget on my dashboard. It is set up like this:

```
Statistic type: Assignee
```

It shows how many tasks are assigned on every team member.

The problem is that it shows a number of tasks and sub-tasks. I want it to show me a number of tasks only.

Is it possible to configure "Issue Statistic" gadget to show a number of tasks (excluding sub-tasks)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the filter that the gadget is using to include a clause such as:
type not in (Sub-task)